# run selenium-python script, from a web browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium and python to restart a device, I already managed to make it work and I restarted the device, now I am trying from a web page with a button or link, to execute the python code remotely, but I can't that the script runs, could you give me an idea or procedure to make the code run by clicking on a button or link.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
import random
import os

def login():

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://192.168.2.2/')

    sleep_random = random.randint(3, 7)
    time.sleep(sleep_random)

    username_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        "/html/body/td[2]/input")
    password_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        "/html/body/td[2]/input")
    username_input.send_keys("Admin")
    password_input.send_keys("12345")

    login_button = browser.find_element_by_id('login')
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.get('http://192.168.2.2/reboot')
    time.sleep(5)
    browserclose = "firefox"
    os.system("pkill "+browserclose)
        
login()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to:

1. Visit a webpage on computer A
2. Click a button on the webpage
3. Have computer A run this script which reboots computer B

If so, you need to put the script behind a server like django or flask running on computer A.  You'll need some authentication and stuff like Apache to host it securely.

Here is a bit of what you'll need on computer A to host the button.  Note that the function `reboot` calls your function `login()`:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/reboot', methods=['POST'])
def reboot():
    print('reboot called')
    login()
    return "Reboot command issued"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    # better to serve a template here, but...
    return """
    <form action="/reboot" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="reboot" value="Reboot" />
    </form>
    """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5010)
```

Oh, and why aren't you using `browser.quit()` instead of that pkill hack?

Comment: It's better to _not_ end your answer with another question, as SO does not have a discussion/thread type format. You can put comments on the question (once if you get enough rep) to clarify something with the OP. I suggest just explaining why `browser.quit()` would be better than "that pkill hack".